# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference in IE11

Tags: javascript, ie11-developer-tools

I am trying to save one report by clicking on button, it is working on IE 9 and IE 10 but not working on IE11 and Chrome. below is my On-click function

```
function SaveReport(thisUser)
{
    thisFormList  = opener.document.getElementById("hiddenFormList").value; 
    thisSortWhere = opener.document.getElementById("hiddenSortWhere").value; 
    if ( thisFormList == "" && thisSortWhere == "")
    {
        alert("Enter the criteria and click -Find- first");
        return false;
    }
}
```

My HTML code

```
<td align="center" style="padding-bottom:10px;"> New Report Name: 
<input type="text" name="newReport" size="50" maxlength="50">
<input type="button" name="SaveReportBtn" `enter code here`
value="Save" onclick="SaveReport('#Client.USERNAME#');" style="width:60px;">
```

Comment: Share your html code please.

Comment: <td align="center" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    New Report Name:
    <input type="text" name="newReport" size="50" maxlength="50">
    <input type="button" name="SaveReportBtn" value="Save"
           onclick="SaveReport('#Client.USERNAME#');" style="width:60px;">

Comment: You can edit your own post (edit text beneath your question) and paste in the code so you can format it properly.

Comment: Please indicate which line the error occurs on. The thing before the `.value` is null. Fix that.

Comment: I am getting value null at below line this is working fine in IE9 and 10 so there is a value. I am getting this issue for some other fields in IE11 as well as some button functionality also not working in IE11 and Chrome                                        thisFormList  = pener.document.getElementById("hiddenFormList").value;

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
opener.document.forms[0].hiddenFormList.value
```

instead of

```
opener.document.getElementById("hiddenFormList").value
```

I was facing the same issue in IE11. It seems due to some reason, getElementById is not very responsive in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're doing this with local files, rather than files served via `http`. That is, the URL of the page starts with `file:` rather than `http:` or `https:`.

The problem is that some browsers, including Chrome, apply the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to local files — that is, one window opened from a local file path cannot access another window opened from a local file path, as though it were a cross-domain request (even though they're both local, and even if they're from the same directory). Others allow it.

If you serve the files via `http`, and they're from the same origin, I suspect you'll find the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you for your Quick reply but I am facing this issue even I serve the files via http (running through my test server not in local)